# cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type pyodbc.Row not supported

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, cx-oracle

When I want to make ETL from SQL Server to Oracle I use the code below. Actually i used process and thread but my code throws error.
After execute the error is `cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type pyodbc.Row not supported`.
Can you help me ?

```
import cx_Oracle
import sys
import pyodbc

BYTES_PER_BATCH = 1024 *256  

# Oracle connection
connection_12c=cx_Oracle.connect()
cur_12c = connection_12c.cursor()
# SQL Server Connection
conn_str = (
        'DRIVER={driver;'
        'SERVER=IP:PORT;'
        'DATABASE=DBNAME;'
        'UID=user;'
        'PWD=pass'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cur = cnxn.cursor()
query = """SELECT Id, OpTime,  GidenData , Action FROM table """
cur.execute(query)
    # Id number
    # Optime Datetime
    # gidendata clob
cur_batch = []
cur_size = 0
for result in cur.fetchall():
    cur_batch.append(result)
    cur_size += sys.getsizeof(result)
    if cur_size > BYTES_PER_BATCH:
        cur_12c.execute("""insert into oracle_table (Id,OpTime,GidenData,Action) values (: 1  ,: 2  ,: 3  ,: 4 ) """,cur_batch)
        cur_batch = []
        cur_size = 0
```

Comment: Immediately after `for result in cur.fetchall():` try adding `result = tuple(result)`

Comment: For any kind of performance with ETL you should use cx_Oracle's `executemany()` to insert multiple rows at a time.  See the cx_Oracle documentation[Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).  If you have really different datatypes, you can use an [inconverter](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/430#issuecomment-622577935), but this is unlikely in your case.  Out of interest, why are you only inserting some of the fetched rows - why fetch data you are not going to insert?

Comment: I used try adding result = tuple(result) but result is same.

Comment: I have really different datatypes.(int,string,clob).Actually My data is bigger. 70 milyon per a day and i used executemany() but i have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are creating a batch of rows, but then calling cursor.execute() which only inserts a single row! Since Oracle also supports PL/SQL with arrays of data, cx_Oracle is assuming that you are passing an array of pyodbc.Row objects, which it doesn't know how to deal with. Instead, you simply need to change cur_12c.execute() to cur_12c.executemany(). Then cx_Oracle will process an array of rows -- which is I believe what you want.

```
import cx_Oracle
import sys
import pyodbc

BYTES_PER_BATCH = 1024 *256  

# Oracle connection
connection_12c=cx_Oracle.connect()
cur_12c = connection_12c.cursor()
# SQL Server Connection
conn_str = (
        'DRIVER={driver;'
        'SERVER=IP:PORT;'
        'DATABASE=DBNAME;'
        'UID=user;'
        'PWD=pass'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cur = cnxn.cursor()
query = """SELECT Id, OpTime,  GidenData , Action FROM table """
cur.execute(query)
    # Id number
    # Optime Datetime
    # gidendata clob
cur_batch = []
cur_size = 0
for result in cur.fetchall():
    cur_batch.append(result)
    cur_size += sys.getsizeof(result)
    if cur_size > BYTES_PER_BATCH:
        cur_12c.executemany("""insert into oracle_table (Id,OpTime,GidenData,Action) values (: 1  ,: 2  ,: 3  ,: 4 ) """,cur_batch)
        cur_batch = []
        cur_size = 0
```